# Invalid memory reference when running dgesvd

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I am trying to calculate SVD using `dgesvd` but encountered the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x10af44a69
#1  0x10af43e35
#2  0x7fff8ae4b529 Segmentation fault: 11
```

My code is the following

```
program calc_pseud3
implicit none
character:: jobu*1, jobvt*1
integer:: N, M, i, j, lwork, info, LDg, LDU, LDVT
real*8:: t0,t1,t2,t3
real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: g_, work, S
real*8, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: g,U,VT,S2,I_check,g_i

call cpu_time(t0)


N = 512*512
M = 2560
lwork = 280000
jobu = 'A'
jobvt = 'A'
LDg = N
LDU = N
LDVT = M

allocate(g_(N*M))
allocate(g(LDg,M))
allocate(g_i(M,N))
allocate(work(lwork))
allocate(S(M))
allocate(S2(N,M))
allocate(U(LDU,N))
allocate(VT(LDVT,M))
allocate(I_check(M,M))

open(1, file='projection.txt')

do i = 1,M
  print *, i
  do j = 1,N
    read(1,*) g_(N*(i-1)+j)
  end do
end do

call cpu_time(t1)
print *, t1-t0
g = reshape(g_, [N, M])
print *, 'Shape of matrix G is ', shape(g)

call cpu_time(t2)
print *, t2-t1

call dgesvd(jobu,jobvt,N,M,g,LDg,S,U,LDU,VT,LDVT,work,lwork,info)

print *, 'here'
S2 = 0.0*g
do j = 1,N
  do i = 1,M
    if (j == i .and. S(i) >= 10**(-4)*S(1)) then        ! If M > N, replace S(i) with S(j)
      S2(j,i) = 1/S(i)
    end if
  end do
end do

g_i = matmul( transpose(VT),matmul(transpose(S2),transpose(U)) )
I_check = matmul(g_i,g)
write (*,1) sum(sum(I_check,1))
1 format(1f10.5)
print *, 'info = ',info

open(4, file='Pseud_inverse.txt')
do i = 1,N*M
write(4,3) g_i
end do
close(4)
3 format(1f10.3)


call cpu_time(t3)
print *, t3-t2


deallocate(g_)
deallocate(g)
deallocate(g_i)
deallocate(work)
deallocate(S)
deallocate(S2)
deallocate(U)
deallocate(VT)
deallocate(I_check)


end
```

That error message appear when calling `dgesvd` so I believe it must be from within this subroutine. I consulted the documentation for that routine and it seems like I haven't violated any requirement.

I have also done the same calculation as above with the same input matrix but `jobu=jobvt='N'` so that `U` and `VT` are not calculated, hence their memory allocation doesn't matter, and it worked. Still no success with the above code.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran]. Add another tag for a specific version if necessary to distinguish.

Comment: Please really take care using correct tags, no wonder your last question didn't get any attention. Please show how you are compiling your code. It is good to enable all debugging options (in gfortran `-g -Wall -fcheck=all -fbacktrace`, in ifort `-g -warn -check -traceback`)

Comment: Actually I didn't know which available words for my current reputation best suited for this question. I tried "singular value" but it doesn't exist.

I don't think the problem is similar to my previous question.
I compiled using `gfortran -llapack calc_pseud3.f90`.

Comment: I am new to this debugging option thing. So, do I just execute that command immediately after running a code which produces some errors?

Comment: No, you compile `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -llapack calc_pseud3.f90`

Comment: This is a programming site, there is absolutely no reason to have a `singular-value` tag. That would be useful at a mathematical site.

Comment: I have done checking the argument's kind, type, and rank many times before I made this post but as far as my awareness is concerned, I can't spot any source of error.

Comment: Had the problem been due to running out of memory, I think the error message would be different from the one I saw.

Comment: @nougako Sorry, beside the error message, I failed to read this sentence "That error message appear when calling dgesvd so I believe it must be from within this subroutine."

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that you have enough memory to allocate such a big matrix, which is about 5GB, even though this is not the source of the error. Anyway, in this cases I would recommend to perform a truncated SVD of the matrix, as you can save a lot of memory.

Also, `lwork` is definied as follows from the documentation:

> The dimension of the array WORK.
>
> ```
>       LWORK >= MAX(1,5*MIN(M,N)) for the paths (see comments inside code):
>          - PATH 1  (M much larger than N, JOBU='N') 
>          - PATH 1t (N much larger than M, JOBVT='N')
>       LWORK >= MAX(1,3*MIN(M,N) + MAX(M,N),5*MIN(M,N)) for the other paths
>       For good performance, LWORK should generally be larger.
> ```

You are passing `N` as rows and `M` as columns to the subroutine. Please note that in the documentation it is used `N` as columns and `M` as rows. Maybe there is a confusion here. Double-check to be sure. So, because of this, `lwork` would be 269824 for your case, which is lower than the value you specified. However, I would try to stick to the documentation.

Finally, I wrote a Fortran module some time ago which helps to perform SVD (truncated - saving memory) using the Lapack library and other useful calculations. You can find it [here](https://github.com/b-fg/LAPACK-Helper). Please feel free to have a look and to use it if it helps. Note it is for the single precision Lapack subroutines, but you shouldn't have any problem to adapt it for the double precision ones.

Comment: Thanks may be I will see your program on Monday when I get back to my office. I hope the fact that it's truncated will not cause severe accuracy lose. The fact is the range of the singular values of my matrix is from 10^4 to 10^(-6).
Yes, that 269824 is the lower bound for lwork that's I why I set 280000.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood "truncated" in your routine name as something that saves memory at the cost of accuracy. After looking at your code I understand that it works as a "mediator" between the user and `sgesvd` that automatically decides which matrix between U and VT that is set as 'S' for saving memory.
However one thing that I found interesting here is that the way you set `lwork`. From your comment above and from the module for case when m>n, why do you set `lwork` to be the same as its lowest requirement `MAX(1,3*MIN(M,N) + MAX(M,N),5*MIN(M,N))`?

Comment: Moreover, what if the input matrix turns out the way such that `lwork >= 5*MIN(M,N)`?

Comment: As is stated in the Wiki of the project, I borrow that subroutine from somewhere else. I agree with your comment, but the way this was set I think it was in order to always get a `lwork` number much bigger than the necessary. Have you tried that? Also, have you tried using that module or using truncated SVD, aka `jobu` or `jobvt = 's'`.

Comment: Using truncated SVD, in my case `U` being truncated, as you suggested, it worked. But until now I still have no clue why the complete SVD fails. Anyway, thank you for sharing your code. It actually inspired me to resort to the truncated version.

Comment: Glad it helped.